# Is registering services/components on Castle Windsor thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, castle-windsor

Is registering components on castle windsor thread-safe?

I.e., can multiple threads simultaneously register components on the same container instance?

(For the record, yes I am aware that doing so is probably insane.)

Comment: I know you've beaten me to the punch here, but what you're doing is probably insane.  Do you want to resolve services registered in one thread in another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite hard to tell whether a complex piece of software like Windsor is thread-safe or not. Windsor has several subsystems and internal services. And each component registration can do lots of stuff (setting up proxies, different lifestyles, custom dependencies...). AFAIK there are no thread-safety specific tests.

However, assuming you're using the default subsystems and your threads don't add custom contributors, subresolvers, etc (i.e. just plain component registration) it should be thread-safe, since the classes involved in component registration look like they're either stateless or properly locked. The [DefaultKernel](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/castleproject/trunk/InversionOfControl/Castle.MicroKernel/DefaultKernel.cs?r=5531) mostly delegates operations to the various subsystems/internal services, and in particular the [DefaultNamingSubSystem](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/castleproject/trunk/InversionOfControl/Castle.MicroKernel/SubSystems/Naming/DefaultNamingSubSystem.cs?r=5358) (the services maps storage subsystem) is properly locked.

I recommend that you ask on the [castle-users](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users) or [castle-dev](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel) google groups, that's where the real Castle gurus are.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this, as it seems you actually did research, which I do appreciate. 

I know it's hard to tell, but I just wanted to know if there was some general knowledge of "Omg don't even think about it" out there. 

Mucho gracias!

Comment: Castle Windsor is designed to be thread safe and there are no known bugs in multithreaded environment. It _should_ work as expected if your code is well designed.